Error importing neopixel library onto QT PY esp32-s2: seesaw neopixel being imported from unexpected location - is seesaw neopixel use intended?
I'm new to programming using circuitpython and can't figure out the cause of this error when attempting to run a simple blinking LED program on my QT PY esp32-s2.
Full error is below:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "code.py", line 9, in 
File "adafruit_seesaw/neopixel.py", line 25, in 
ImportError: seesaw neopixel being imported from unexpected location - is seesaw neopixel use intended?
I have both the library, neopixel.mpy and its dependency library adafruit_pixelbuf.mpy in CIRCUITPY/lib already.
I copied the code from here to try and test my microcontroller setup
https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit_Learning_System_Guides/blob/main/Welcome_to_CircuitPython/code.py
The error is coming from the line
import neopixel

Are you using CircuitPython or MicroPython? They're different and they work differently. You seem to be referring to CircuitPython in the question but you've tagged it micropython and say you're using that. Also it would help if you would edit the question and include at least code.py at least up to where the error happens.

Edited to clarify, I am usng circuitPython
